# How to "resurrect" an old question with no answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been trying to find a solution to a problem of mine (obvious situation when using Stack Overflow). I [found a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810953/how-to-read-a-non-standard-dbf-memo-file) which is asking the exact thing I'm looking for, but it does not yet have any answers.

Besides a bounty, how can this question be "bumped up" to get, well, basically re-asked, to get more attention, without creating a new duplicate?

Comment: You could improve the question, that bumps it up. Don't forget to make it obvious you pushed it today because you want an answer though, or people will think there's just someone polishing old questions for no reason. Still, maybe asking a new question, linking to the old one and closing the old one as a duplicate will work better. I wish you luck, though I cannot help myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm perplexed - this is what bounties were designed to do. Use a bounty.

Comment: Indeed, I was kinda expecting this answer

Comment: @JerryDodge: indeed. What's wrong with it? Your question is similar to, how do I best cook an apple pie without apples or pie dough?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Already created a bounty.

Comment: @JerryDodge: bump it up then. The higher the bounty, the greater the interest.

Comment: I think the only point missing here is that you're right not to want to duplicate it - but that duplicate if you made one would likely also have little to no interest, especially if there's no interest with a bounty attached to the old.