# What do I do if my question has received no answers or comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, asking-questions

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301451/android-sounds-not-playing-after-successive-button-clicks) seems like a good and useful question.  It has received no attention. Only 12 views. What should I do?  Seems like it would be bad form to re-ask it.

[Android sounds not playing after successive button clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301451/android-sounds-not-playing-after-successive-button-clicks)

Comment: I think there are two strategies. First, be patient. Second, place a bounty on it after two days. See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

Comment: What purpose would re-asking it *possibly* serve? It has already been asked, and it is still there.

Comment: Most of the canonicals were left behind in the Great Meta Schism. There are several asked here about getting answers to *old* questions (e.g. [How to "resurrect" an old question with no answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252225)), but not really any about questions less than 24 hours old. No surprise: the answer is basically "have a little patience". Doesn't get a lot of upvotes.

Comment: Now it has gotten a response. I think perhaps I misunderstand the nature of how questions are viewed. I generally start getting answers within minutes or hours. I was assuming that if a question didn't' start getting attention after a few hours then it simply disappeared down the queue. So, be patient really is the answer. Sorry folks. Anyway, once again, I do think it was a reasonable and useful question in case another person had the same idea. Not sure why it was downvoted so many times.

Comment: @abalter Because people ***love*** to down vote on meta. Even if it's a perfectly valid and good quality question. It seems most people don't understand the indented purpose of voting here.

Comment: At least... you'll get the "tumbleweed" badge :)

Answer (score 19):

To get a more viewer and answers to your post you need:

1. Add specific details so problem is clear.
2. Add and make proper formatting for code.
3. Relevant tags are really important to be linked.
4. Share with your friends or community you know can answer.
5. Offer bounty to attract more viewers to post.

Answer (score 6):

To attract viewers,

1. Make sure the title is clear and provides a hint to the problem you are facing
2. Tag your question with more than 2 tags (or at least 2 tags)
3. Use a chatroom (but don't use it always)
4. If you want more viewers, offer a bounty.

Comment: Most of this information was already said. Other than "Use a chatroom".