# How do I improve visibility of a question as a newcomer?

Tags: discussion, support

I see my question has been marked as a duplicate of

[What do I do if my question has received no answers or comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261078/what-do-i-do-if-my-question-has-received-no-answers-or-comments)

However all of the answers given in this post (with the exception of going to the chatroom), have already been covered, and explained why they aren't relevant to my question. This other question and many similar questions like it. All have answers targeted towards most members. While my question is specifically asking how to improve visibility as a newcomer. Which renders most of the standard answers like (put a bounty on it) impossible, due to our lack of reputation.

---

A few days ago I ran into a difficult problem I couldn't solve myself. And I went to ask a question on StackOverflow. However it only got 28 views, 0 comments and 0 answers.

[Horizontal constraint not working correctly in a UIScrollView. (programatic constraints)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120457/constraint-issue-in-subview-of-uiscrollview-programatic-constraints)

I read through the StackOverflow suggestions on how to improve my questions. And I've edited my post several times. However I havn't been able to get any luck getting some views. (If no one sees my question, how am I able to get help?)

So I thought I might be doing something wrong, as my question shouldn't actually be too complex? It's a rather basic thing, yet completely uncovered.

I've spent quite some time reading up on how to get some more views.

The most common suggestion is of course giving it a bounty. However since I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow. I don't have 50 reputation to give away.

I also noticed that my post doesn't show up again when I make edits to my question. (I guess that only happens for higher ranked users as well?)

I'm having quite some trouble figuring out, how  to get my question noticed as a user with a low reputation. I don't have any people on any of my social networks, that are able to help me, so sharing it on facebook and such isn't going to help any.

My tags should be the most relevant to my question.

I only put the code that is relevant to my problem. I showed that I have tried plenty of diferent things to fix it, and I even found the root of my problem. Just have no clue on how to fix it.

While I do realise that a lot of people might not be able to help answer my question. My problem seems to be more related to the fact that I havn't gotten a single new view since a couple of hours after it was posted.

And my issue should concern a fairly simple category (constraints). Which the vast majority of IOs developers has in their application. So if people saw the title, I'm sure it would be clicked on.

So how does one as a newcomer draw attention to a question?

Comment: Well, your meta post *will* certainly cause in increase in views to your question, but sometimes this is not a good thing.

Comment: @Hovercraft I'm not posting on here to get views. I'm trying to figure out how you're supposed to get started on Stack Overflow as a newcomer.

Comment: I understand, but regardless of your aims, this question **will** direct eyes to your question, something called the "meta" effect, which *may* increase your chance of getting answers or comments, but as noted above, can sometimes be a bad thing, as it can result in down-votes and close-votes.

Comment: That's the job of those 28 people that read your question.  If it was an interesting problem and attracts good answers then they'll vote it up and post answers so the question stays active longer.  That didn't happen by the looks of it, 28 is however not a terrible number.  You can only buy more exposure with a bounty.  Maybe later when you collect enough rep.

Comment: @CoolGuy Nothing in that question has any relevance to my question? I've mentioned all the answers to that question in my post. And why they are not helping me? My question (imo) is concise and clear, it has the correct tags, the code is formatted correctly, I don't have anyone else to share it with, I can't offer a bounty since I'm a newcomer? I know there's plenty of questions out there, regarding visibility of posts. But my question is specifically about improving visibility as a newcomer. Which means the answers to these posts (unless I missed some) doesn't work for me?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see your point. It was not my intention to get views from the meta forum. As most likely these views as you say, will result in downvotes, especially since the people viewing it from here most likely won't have answers. Should I remove the link to my question? I put it up there, so people could see that it wasn't a "2 line question" or something like that.

Comment: If you remove the link people will find it via your profile...

Comment: And you might want to read [Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) where the concensus seems to be: Yes.

Comment: @rene good point. I'll edit my post to make my edits more friendly for first time readers. Thanks!

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not complaining about not getting help. I'm simply trying to figure out how to go about questions as a newcomer. I understand that not everyone can, have the time or even want to help out. I'm trying to figure out what I can do better. No need to be offensive.

Comment: `"I understand that not everyone can, have the time or even want to help out"` -- nor the expertise. I for one am completely ignorant of the topics of your question, and I'm sure that I'm not alone. Your speed of help may depend on the number of [tag:swift] experts that frequent this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels of course :) that's what I meant with "`not everyone can`" I should probably have elaborated on that a bit more. Anyhow, I'm of course not asking for help with swift on the meta forum. It's a more general question about getting help for a "dead" question as a newcomer, when most of the usual ways is unavailable. I'm by no means complaining about the speed of questions, I'm just trying to figure out what I can do better, or if I was doing something wrong. :)

Comment: Well, thanks to the Meta effect you got a +1 from me for a clear question, bells & whistles included. But ... it was asked only 3 days ago. Too soon to go an cry for help: this spans a weekend, and perhaps the field experts like to do something else on a Saturday night (can't think of what). Wait another week or so.

Comment: WTH, bounty added.

Comment: woah. Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels!